# Return the index of an item in an Array in Hive

Tags: arrays, hive

I have an array of released versions of a product that looks like this:

```
version_release    
[1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 9]
```

I'd like to be able to find the next (or previous) version of the product knowing the version in question.

For instance, I'm looking at version 7, the next version is 8, the previous version is 5.

In Hive, is there a way to

1. find the index of "7" in the array (4)
2. increment (or decrement) that index to return "8" (index 5) or "5" (index 3), respectively?

Comment: perhaps you should use `indexOf([value])` to return the position of a value, then add or subtract one from the index position.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't able to find good documentation on that due to site maps giving me the "index of hive" sites. Do you have a syntactical example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manipulating arrays *in situ* is not very SQL-ish. You could try to "[PosExplode()](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Built-inTable-GeneratingFunctions%28UDTF%29)" that column first, generating 1 record per array value, then JOIN values with adjacent positions(1 vs. 2, 2 vs. 3...) to get a sense of successorship.

Or maybe the [BrickHouse library](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/wiki/Collect-UDFs) has something more efficient for your use case.